# few files listed when running "sudo dpkg --listfiles apache2"

Tags: apt, apache2, dpkg

I installed apache2 by running `sudo apt-get install apache2`, but it seems that something wrong happened. Below is the output. Why?

```
me@mycomputer:/usr/share/apache2$ sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apache2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
me@mycomputer:/usr/share/apache2$ sudo dpkg --listfiles apache2
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/bug
/usr/share/bug/apache2
/usr/share/bug/apache2/control
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/bug/apache2/script
/usr/share/doc/apache2
```

**UPDATE**

Running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2`, output is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dovecot-core libdbd-sqlite3-perl dovecot-imapd dnsmasq
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,498 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 194506 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace apache2 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10 (using .../apache2_2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement apache2 ...
Setting up apache2 (2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10) ...
```

Running `sudo service apache2 status`, output is:

```
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
Apache2 is running (pid 22408).
```

It seems that apache2 is running, but how to list the contents of apache2? 
Also, there are files in /etc/apache2:

```
/etc/apache2$ ls
apache2.conf  envvars     magic           mods-enabled  sites-available
conf.d        httpd.conf  mods-available  ports.conf    sites-enabled
```

Why I can not list all of them?

**UPDATE**

**No idea why downvoted??? Maybe this question is too simple to post here???**

Comment: Try reinstalling it: `apt-get install --reinstall apache2`

Comment: Tried, see the update

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @muru Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release: 12.04
Codename: precise

Comment: @muru It seems that apache2 is running, and there are files in /etc/apache2, but why failed to list of these files? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is [normal for 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/apache2/filelist), where it is [a metapackage](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/apache2). The actual `apache2` binaries, modules, etc. are part of the [`apache2-mpm-*`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/apache2-mpm-worker/filelist), [`apache2-bin`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/apache2-bin/filelist) and [`apache2-common`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/apache2-common/filelist) packages. In newer versions of Ubuntu, the `apache2` package also provides configuration files.

Comment: Thanks, but how to list all the actual packages related to apache2?

Comment: `apt-cache policy apache2*`, maybe.